# Tracking 502 bad gateway error

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, server, nginx

I moved my Wordpress site to WP Engine and now I constantly get 502 errors. I spoke with support and they said that its because I have a lot of DB queries. I ran some tests and my frontpage only has 95 queries and page size is about 500kb. Most inner pages are around 60 queries. All queries are very short.

Some people tell me its common with WP Engine because they run nginx.

Why do I keep getting these errors and is there a way to track how many of them happen on daily basis?

P.S.

WP Engine log is empty so cant see the 502's there.

Comment: What is your site address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you would be able to track the 502 errors is if you had access to the Nginx server config file. Other than that you may want to try some caching plugins to lighten up the database load. I've recently installed Memcached Redux and noticed a performance boost.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/memcached-redux/

Your support contact at WP Engine should be able to guide you toward some caching plugins that they recommend and approve of for their platform.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/cache

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/object-cache